# Can motivate be used as a negative word?

Tags: negation

Can the word "motivate"be used in a negative situation? 
For example,
"the Stamp Act motivated people to voice their opposition"

Comment: If people were opposed to the Stamp Act, and voiced their opposition, that action would have seemed "positive" to them (it was done in accordance with their beliefs).

Comment: Voicing opposition is not negative.

Comment: I am opposed to Brexit, and voice my opposition at every opportunity, and it feels very positive.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/4a/1f/af4a1fb6d025ff7eaf802162db48bb64.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The verb 'motivate' can simply mean to "influence a person or people to do something", with no "positive" or "negative" meaning:

> to cause someone to behave in a particular way

However, it is often used to describe efforts to make people do more, do better, or make positive choices, and "motivational" speeches, posters, slogans, etc, are used for that kind of purpose:

> to make someone want to do something well

[Motivate (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/motivate)

Answer (score 4):

"Motivation" is a neutral term.  The same set of circumstances can be said to *motivate* someone to do either positive or negative acts.

> Extreme poverty **motivated** her to start her own business.
>
> Extreme poverty **motivated** her to commit several robberies.

In any case, "voicing opposition" is not normally considered a *negative* act.  As with "motivate" it's a *neutral* expression whose connotations depend on the exact circumstances of the opposition.

For example, in the TV series "The Simpsons" the misanthropic owner of the town's nuclear power plant often *voices his opposition* to things like charity or quality of life, which most would consider to be a "negative" opinion:

[image]

Comment: _"In any case, 'voicing opposition' is not normally considered a negative act."_ That _entirely_ depends on the location and on the context. I think we should leave this borderline political statement out of it! The rest of your answer is great.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  There's nothing "political" about it, as the mere act of "voicing opposition" is never considered *in and of itself* to be negative.  As with "motivate", it is a *neutral* term that relies entirely on context to be negative or positive.  But I will clarify this in my answer.

Comment: Voicing opposition may certainly be considered generally negative in some value systems.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Certainly if you believe so, provide an example.

Comment: @Andrew - maybe some people think that support [of anything] is somehow "positive" and opposition [to anything] is somehow "negative" in some narrow sense?